My GoogleOAuth2SuccessHandler is Ignored by Spring Security
Created using thymeleaf and prviously it working fine but currently not Spring security ignoring my GoogleAuthSuccessHandler I debug it method is not callled by SecurityConfig
This is GoogleOAuth2SuccessHandler class `
@Autowired
RoleRepository roleRepository;

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
OAuth2AuthenticationToken token =(OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
String email = token.getPrincipal().getAttributes().get("email").toString();
if(userRepository.findUserByEmail(email).isPresent()) {
    
}
else {
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(token.getPrincipal().getAttributes().get("given_name").toString());
    user.setLastName("user");
    user.setEmail(email);
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    roles.add(roleRepository.findById(2).get());
    user.setRoles(roles);
    userRepository.save(user);
}

redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");

`
This is  Security Config Class Via Extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Spring 2.7.0
`
@Autowired
GoogleOAuth2SuccessHandler googleOAuth2SuccessHandler;

@Autowired
CustomUserDetailService customUserDetailService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http.authorizeRequests()
    
    .antMatchers("/","/shop/**","/register/**","/forgotPassword/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/working/**").hasAuthority("WORKER")
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
    .usernameParameter("email")
    .passwordParameter("password")
    .and()
    .oauth2Login()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .successHandler(this.googleOAuth2SuccessHandler)
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
    .and()
    .csrf()
    .disable();
    
}
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService);
}
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**","/static/**","/images/**","/productImages/**","/css/**","/js/**");
}

`
I want to resolve my problem couple of month ago it working finely.
